# What is a mesh/loop in a circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

I am a total beginner in electronics. I think it's apparently easy to identify all the concepts in the tutorials and books. The problem is that the concept is exemplified only a few times in simple circuits and when I try to analyze circuits "not didactic" I can not identify certain concepts, including the mesh / loop.

Everywhere says "meshes are closed paths between two points", "the voltage is divided between the mesh resistors!" but it seems very vague.

Ok, let's say a mesh is a closed path from A to B, but what if this path is cut by a branch, it will remain a closed path or become two spots?

In the examples I see only a square connecting the positive to the negative of the source but can not see it in larger circuits!

What is the easiest way to understand this?

Comment: Dave Jones put up a couple of videos explaining this last week. Take a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WBfAEeEzDlg) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8f-2yXiYmRI)

Comment: @KeithMiller, thank you very much! Great lesson! Some teachers make everything look really easy and simple just by their personality!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of a mesh as 'one possible path for current to flow'.

So in a circuit with many nodes there are many possible meshes or paths. But that doesn't mean that a mesh is exclusive, no, in fact you can make up meshes or paths from other paths that exist.
In mesh analysis though, its helpful to isolate each mesh so that the current around that path is unique.

Once you have identified each mesh, apply Kirchoffs Current law and Ohms law for each loop/path/mesh and solve the simultaneous equations to find all the different currents.

Comment: Look the first image of circuit here http://www.estudar.info/engenheiro-tem-que-estudar/circuitos-eletricos/10-circuitos-mistos-serie-e-paralelo/exercicio-resolvido-02-analise-de-circuitos-eletricos-mistos-serie-e-paralelo. You tell me all the possible paths between R1, R2, R3, R4 and R5 to C spot are different loops?

Comment: In that circuit you can simplify a little by combining the parallel resistors and think of them as one resistor with a new combined current Ix = Ia + Ib. Then make a new simplified circuit. In electronics and indeed engineering we always analyze by breaking things down into simpler small chunks then build the circuit back up again.

Answer (score 0):

Now I realize the concept of LOOP is every possible path starting at a node and ending in another node.

The voltage's sum of resistors of any path between A and B is equal to X. Simply because the voltage is not divided between the nodes.